# Why can't a node in a linked list be responsible for deleting itself? (C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list

My idea is that once the first node is deleted from the linked list class then the rest will follow. My implementation does not work in practice. Is there solution to deleting a whole list node by node instead of the linked list deleting all of them? Should my `nodeT` have a destructor?

Linked list implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "nodeT.h"
class linkedListSort
{
public:
    int print();
      //Function to output the elements of the list
      //Postcondition: Elements of the list are output on the 
      //   standard output device. Member current is reset to beginning node
      //   and currentIndex is reset to 0
      //Returns:  number of items printed in the list
      //          also outputs error if number of items printed
      //          does not equal the length of the list

    void insertAt(int location, elemType& insertItem);
      //Function to insert an item in the list at the 
      //position specified by location. The item to be inserted 
      //is passed as a parameter to the function.
      //Postcondition: Starting at location, the elements of the
      //    list are shifted down, list[location] = insertItem;,
      //    and length++;. If the list is full or location is
      //    out of range, an appropriate message is displayed.

      linkedListSort(int size = 100);

      ~linkedListSort();

protected:
  //consider making const
  nodeT<elemType> *beginningNode;  // handle to the beginning of the list
  nodeT<elemType> *current;  // pointer to current node
  int currentIndex;  //int representing which node in the list current is pointing to
  int length;      //to store the length of the list
  int maxSize;     //to store the maximum size of the list

  };

template <class elemType>
linkedListSort<elemType>::linkedListSort(int size)
{
  if (size < 0)
  {
    cerr << "The array size must be positive. Creating "
      << "an array of size 100. " << endl;

    maxSize = 100;
  }
  else
    maxSize = size;

  beginningNode = NULL;
  current = NULL; // initialize to empty linked list
  length = 0;
  currentIndex = -1; // there is no item that current points to
}

template <class elemType>
linkedListSort<elemType>::~linkedListSort()
{
  delete beginningNode;  // this should delete all linked list items ( see nodeT destructor )
}
```

linked list node implementation:

```
template <class elemType>
class nodeT {
public:
  nodeT(elemType& infoParam, nodeT<elemType> *linkParam);  //standard
  nodeT(elemType& infoParam);  //if unlinked node (ex. last item)
  nodeT();
  //copy constructor
  nodeT(nodeT<elemType>& node);
  ~nodeT();
  elemType *info;
  nodeT *link;
};

template<class elemType>
nodeT<elemType>::nodeT(elemType& infoParam, nodeT<elemType> *linkParam) {
  info = &infoParam;
  link = linkParam;
}

//when link is null (last item and uncircular)
template<class elemType>
nodeT<elemType>::nodeT(elemType& infoParam) {
  info = &infoParam;
  link = NULL;
}

//in case node is needed before info or link is known (default)
template<class elemType>
nodeT<elemType>::nodeT() {
  info = NULL;
  link = NULL;
}

template<class elemType>
nodeT<elemType>::nodeT(nodeT<elemType>& node) {
  info = new elemType();
  if (node.link != NULL)
    link = new nodeT();

  *info = *(node.info);  // copy by value
  if (node.link != NULL)
    *link = *(node.link);
  else
    link = NULL;
}

template<class elemType>
nodeT<elemType>::~nodeT() {
  delete info;
  if (link != NULL)
    delete link;
}
```

The last part of the node implementation is the node destructor. If the member of `nodeT` link is of type `nodeT` then the code `delete link` will call the same destructor but just on another instance. Therefore each node should destroy itself once the first node is destroyed. The first node is destroyed in the linked list implementation as such: `delete beginningNode` where `beginningNode` always points to the first node in the linked list.

Am I close to a solution? Or am I just going down a rabbit hole that C++ doesn't want you to go down?

The actual error has to do with an assertion failing. Then eventually I can copy this to my clipboard:  "Unhandled exception at 0x553056E8 (msvcr120d.dll) in chap10Ex1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000002."

Comment: I can add code if you guys need to reproduce the actual error. I just thought this might be answerable by c++ gurus in theory.

Comment: Unrelated to your assertion (which stems from a null-pointer dereference; check your code) I warn you that `delete` -ing from the destructor will give some undesired consequences. Consider (a) `delete` invokes a destructor call, which invokes a delete, which invokes a destructor cal which invokes delete... repeat for each node in the list. Sounds fine until you try it on a list with, say, 1,000,000 nodes. That's when you discover how unexpectedly shallow your call stack can be before an overrun, a crashed process, etc. There are iterative alternatives.

Comment: I did not think of that. But if I'm not deallocating the memory who is? As in if I don't delete the pointer members of `nodeT` (info and link) and instead loop through each node and semantically `delete node` for every item then aren't I leaving scrap pointers around?

Answer (score 1):

Technically your nodes aren't responsible for deleting *themselves*, they're responsible for deleting the next node in the list.

This may seem attractive, but there are some implications here that you may not have considered. First, what @WhozCraig said in a comment that you're going to end up building quite a deep call stack of destructors for a big list.

Secondly, if you managed to build yourself a circular link chain you're going to go all the way round it and then hit undefined behaviour when you try to delete the first node for the second time. Nothing in your code prevents that kind of misuse - these kinds of guarantees are one of the advantages of using a container class for the list which hides the operation of the nodes themselves from the clients.

I think there's also an issue here about ownership. Nodes don't allocate each other, but they are responsible for deleting each other, which means that each node *owns* the next node in the list. This may not be obvious from the API you provide, which requires the user of the list to create new nodes, but then when you add them to the list the list takes responsibility for deleting them. This means in client code there's no balance between `new` and `delete`, which is going to look a bit odd.

However, much worse in ownership terms is that the list node destructor calls `delete info`, which is created in one of the constructors as the address of a reference passed in which *might not even be on the heap*. You can't tell, nobody's made any promises there. At the very least you need to accept a pointer instead of a reference, as that's a hint that an ownership transfer is happening. Even better would be to accept a `std::unique_ptr<elemType>`, which makes the transfer of ownership very explicit (you can still provide access to the contents via a raw pointer).

In general I would advise that if a data structure is going to take responsibility for deleting something that data structure should also be responsible for creating it. Otherwise, you should leave it alone. STL containers don't delete contained pointers - if you delete a `std::vector<int *>` you have to delete all the `int *` members yourself first. This gives the user flexibility - they don't have to store pointers to things which are on the heap - and it means it's consistent - those responsible for creating something should, in general, also be responsible for disposing of it. It also means the `std::list<T>` can contain any `T` - including pointers. What happens if you try to instantiate a `nodeT<int *>`? What happens when its destructor runs?

So I'd say if you're going to have nodes deleting each other you should also have nodes creating each other (and don't let the user do it). And if you're going to have nodes deleting their data items you should most definitely also be creating those data items. Or better, just leave that alone and *don't touch the lifecycle of something passed to you by reference*.

Comment: I wish I had the knowledge to understand all of your answer. I'm not sure why "a reference passed in which might not even be on the heap." is important. Are you saying that a reference which is passed to node may already be deleted? Or something to that effect? Someone else nulled it out?

Comment: It's hugely important. The heap is where things created using `new` are stored. You can only call `delete` on things which were created by `new`. If they're on the stack (this is where local variables go) then `delete` is undefined behaviour and will probably just crash. (The heap also has things created by `malloc()`, which must be deleted using `free()`). If you don't understand this you need to read up on it because a proper understanding of memory is _vital_ for a C++ programmer, especially if you're implementing data structures.

Comment: I have these basic concepts in mind. I still do not implement them correctly everytime however. There is a method that I wrote and didn't post that actually creates nodes for the linked list. (insert). Reviewing these concepts is always important when looking at actual code.